# ERROR cannot generate allure report data using Allure 2, Maven, Java 9 and TestNG

Tags: allure

I am just configuring Allure 2 to run in my fairly new intelliJ Maven project.

A copy of my POM is attached.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 
http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>com.intellihub.msats.automation</groupId>
<artifactId>b2bresponder</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <aspectj.version>1.8.10</aspectj.version>
    <allure.version>1.5.0</allure.version>
</properties>


<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
        <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
        <version>6.11</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-java -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
        <version>3.6.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.opencsv/opencsv -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.opencsv</groupId>
        <artifactId>opencsv</artifactId>
        <version>3.3</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.9.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.9.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.qameta.allure/allure-testng -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.qameta.allure</groupId>
        <artifactId>allure-testng</artifactId>
        <version>2.0-BETA16</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.xml.bind/jaxb-api -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>ru.yandex.qatools.allure</groupId>
        <artifactId>allure-testng-adaptor</artifactId>
        <version>${allure.version}</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>io.qameta.allure</groupId>
            <artifactId>allure-maven</artifactId>
            <version>2.9</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-report-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.20.1</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.20</version>
            <configuration>
                <useSystemClassLoader>false</useSystemClassLoader>
                <argLine>
                    -javaagent:"${settings.localRepository}/org/aspectj/aspectjweaver/${aspectj.version}/aspectjweaver-${aspectj.version}.jar"
                </argLine>
                <properties>
                    <property>
                        <name>listener</name>
                        <value>ru.yandex.qatools.allure.testng.AllureTestListener</value>
                    </property>
                    <systemProperties>
                        <property>
                            <name>allure.results.directory</name>
                            <value>${project.build.directory}/allure-results</value>
                        </property>
                    </systemProperties>
                </properties>
            </configuration>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
                    <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
                    <version>${aspectj.version}</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
                    <version>2.3.0</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

<reporting>
    <excludeDefaults>true</excludeDefaults>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>io.qameta.allure</groupId>
            <artifactId>allure-maven</artifactId>
            <version>2.9</version>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</reporting>
```

Things go great until it comes to preparing the allure report.  I am getting the NoClassDefFoundError.

```
[INFO] Tests run: 4, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 154.871 s - in TestSuite
[INFO]
[INFO] Results:
[INFO]
[INFO] Tests run: 4, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0
[INFO]
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-site-plugin:3.3:site (default-site) @ b2bresponder ---
[INFO] configuring report plugin io.qameta.allure:allure-maven:2.9
[WARNING] No project URL defined - decoration links will not be relativized!
[INFO] Rendering site with org.apache.maven.skins:maven-default-skin:jar:1.0 skin.
[INFO] Skipped "Allure" report, file "allure-maven.html" already exists for the English version.
[INFO] Skipped "Allure" report, file "allure-maven.html" already exists for the English version.
[INFO] Skipped "Allure" report, file "allure-maven.html" already exists for the English version.
[INFO] Generating "Allure" report    --- allure-maven:2.9
[INFO] Allure installation directory C:\Users\Documents\SELENIUM\projects\b2bresponder/.allure
[INFO] Try to finding out allure 2.0.1
[INFO] Generate Allure report (aggregate) with version 2.0.1
[INFO] Generate Allure report to C:\Users\Documents\SELENIUM\projects\b2bresponder\target\site/allure-maven-plugin
[INFO] Found results directory C:\Users\Documents\SELENIUM\projects\b2bresponder\target\allure-results
[INFO] Can't find information about categories.
[INFO] Generate report to C:\Users\Documents\SELENIUM\projects\b2bresponder\target\site\allure-maven-plugin
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlElement
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.module.jaxb.JaxbAnnotationIntrospector.<init>(JaxbAnnotationIntrospector.java:139)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.module.jaxb.JaxbAnnotationIntrospector.<init>(JaxbAnnotationIntrospector.java:126)
    at io.qameta.allure.context.JacksonContext.<init>(JacksonContext.java:24)
    at io.qameta.allure.ConfigurationBuilder.useDefault(ConfigurationBuilder.java:50)
    at io.qameta.allure.Commands.createReportConfiguration(Commands.java:158)
    at io.qameta.allure.Commands.generate(Commands.java:63)
    at io.qameta.allure.CommandLine.run(CommandLine.java:129)
    at java.base/java.util.Optional.orElseGet(Optional.java:361)
    at io.qameta.allure.CommandLine.main(CommandLine.java:72)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:582)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:185)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:496)
    ... 9 more
[ERROR] Can't generate allure report data
org.apache.commons.exec.ExecuteException: Process exited with an error: 1 (Exit value: 1)
    at org.apache.commons.exec.DefaultExecutor.executeInternal(DefaultExecutor.java:404)
    at org.apache.commons.exec.DefaultExecutor.execute(DefaultExecutor.java:166)
    at org.apache.commons.exec.DefaultExecutor.execute(DefaultExecutor.java:153)
    at io.qameta.allure.maven.AllureCommandline.execute(AllureCommandline.java:88)
    at io.qameta.allure.maven.AllureCommandline.generateReport(AllureCommandline.java:59)
    at io.qameta.allure.maven.AllureGenerateMojo.generateReport(AllureGenerateMojo.java:213)
    at io.qameta.allure.maven.AllureGenerateMojo.executeReport(AllureGenerateMojo.java:137)
    at org.apache.maven.reporting.AbstractMavenReport.generate(AbstractMavenReport.java:255)
    at org.apache.maven.plugins.site.ReportDocumentRenderer.renderDocument(ReportDocumentRenderer.java:219)
    at org.apache.maven.doxia.siterenderer.DefaultSiteRenderer.renderModule(DefaultSiteRenderer.java:319)
    at org.apache.maven.doxia.siterenderer.DefaultSiteRenderer.render(DefaultSiteRenderer.java:135)
    at org.apache.maven.plugins.site.SiteMojo.renderLocale(SiteMojo.java:175)
    at org.apache.maven.plugins.site.SiteMojo.execute(SiteMojo.java:138)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:134)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:208)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:154)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:146)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:309)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:194)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:107)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:993)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:345)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:191)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 02:47 min
[INFO] Finished at: 2017-11-07T14:55:02+10:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 32M/107M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-site-plugin:3.3:site (default-site) on project b2bresponder: Error during page generation: Error rendering Maven report: Could not generate the report: Can't generate allure report data: Process exited with an error: 1 (Exit value: 1) ->
[Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

I had this problem when I first integrated Allure 2 however I resolved this by adding the jaxb-api dependency.

Now when I comes to generating the Allure report I am getting the same error.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JAXB issues should be [fixed](https://github.com/allure-framework/allure2/issues/638) in 2.4.1 version.
But that's not a single issue in your case, as I see several problems in provided `pom.xml`:

- There's a mess of 2 different Allure TestNG adapter versions.
- There's no report version specified in plugin's section.
- Wrong report generation command is used. Check the official [allure-maven](https://github.com/allure-framework/allure-maven) page for details.

Comment: Thanks Sergey, I got it working now with the correct report generation command.  Thanks for pointing out the other issues with my POM.  I am no expert and was trying to cobble something together based on previous commands and the help on the Allure website.  Got there in the end.